# How to check if a term has a published content associated with it?

Tags: theming, 8

I have taxonomy term list called clients. I have managed to list all the terms on the taxonomy term list page by adding contents for each term, some contents are published some are not. 
what I want to do is check and remove the term page link for those terms whose contents are not published and display them without the link.

Answer (score 4):

There is an existing Question that handles this for views 2 and views 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421972/how-to-display-only-taxonomy-terms-with-nodes-associated-to-in-views-2

Comment: I have checked the link you gave me.... it differs from what i'm trying to achieve. I have listed all the terms by adding contents for each term some published so not. what I want to do is remove the term page link for those term whose contents are unpublished but the term listed without the term page link.